# Exporting a Line of Data From One Data Table to Another

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-insert

The code below is for a project I'm working on. I'm having some issues with my PHP code and am in need of help.

I have a button on my data table named "Export". When the button is clicked, I wish to copy the data on that row and move it to an archive.

```
<?php

    function val($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    
    $ticket_id = $_GET["ticket_id"];
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM activeticket WHERE ticket_id='$ticket_id' INSERT INTO `ticketarchive`(`name`, `account_num`, `department`, `ticket_desc`, `email`, `assigned`, `status`, `fibre_site`) VALUES ([name],[account_num],[department],[ticket_desc],[email],[assigned],[status],[fibre_site])";
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully. Record ID is: ";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Below is the error that this produces:

> Error: SELECT * FROM activeticket WHERE ticket_id='1' INSERT INTO
> `archiveticket`(`name`, `account_num`, `department`, `ticket_desc`,
> `email`, `assigned`, `status`, `fibre_site`) VALUES
> ([name],[account_num],[department],[ticket_desc],[email],[assigned],[status],[fibre_site])
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'INSERT INTO `archiveticket`(`name`, `account_num`, `department`,
> `ticket_desc`, `' at line 1

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Test your query in MySQL Workbench or PhpMyAdmin first. It looks like you copy a record identified by ticket_id but not delete it from the originating table, hence it is not "moved" but copied. To correct the syntax, look at the sample in https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

First execute the select query and after that execute the insert one. Right now you are trying to run them both and this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a PHP issue you're having, you just seem to be unfamiliar with SQL.
What you're trying to do is insert the result of a SELECT query into a table. This isn't the way to do it at all.
What you're looking for is :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ticketarchive`(
    `name`,
    `account_num`,
    `department`,
    `ticket_desc`,
    `email`,
    `assigned`,
    `status`,
    `fibre_site`
)
SELECT
    `name`,
    `account_num`,
    `department`,
    `ticket_desc`,
    `email`,
    `assigned`,
    `status`,
    `fibre_site`
FROM
    `activeticket`
WHERE
    `ticket_id` = $ticket_id"
```

For more information, [read here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/).

I'd also advice you look into parametrized queries to avoid SQL injections.